# Select records that in a string column has a minimum of occurences from another string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a challenge dealing with selecting person records that in a name column has at least 2 occurrences from a name string parameter.

```
create table #persons (id int not null, [name] nvarchar(200) not null  )

insert into #persons VALUES (1, 'Paul Nelson')
insert into #persons VALUES (2, 'Paul Eric Smith')
insert into #persons VALUES (3, 'Paul Parsons Cline')
insert into #persons VALUES (4, 'Greg Olav Smith')
insert into #persons VALUES (5, 'Paul Henry Gregory Hansson')
insert into #persons VALUES (6, 'Parsons Henry Smith')

declare @name_to_search_for nvarchar(200) = 'Paul Smith Parsons'
```

What I want is to selected the id from #persons having two or more occurrences of name parts from `@name_to_search_for`.

In the example above I want to get the result set

```
2
3
6
```

What I have tried is to use `STRING_SPLIT(@name_to_search_for, ' ')` to get a resultset that I can cross join to #persons combined with a function to count string occurrences, but I cannot get it all the way.

Hope someone has some good ideas here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't know anyone named [Major Major Major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_Major_Major_Major) by any chance? General reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split both the name column you are searching along with the @name_to_search_for and join on the split values.

Then get a count by [id], [name] and apply HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2

Something like this, I just changed your example to a table variable:

```
DECLARE @persons TABLE
    (
        [id] INT NOT NULL
      , [name] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO @persons
VALUES ( 1, 'Paul Nelson' )
     , ( 2, 'Paul Eric Smith' )
     , ( 3, 'Paul Parsons Cline' )
     , ( 4, 'Greg Olav Smith' )
     , ( 5, 'Paul Henry Gregory Hansson' )
     , ( 6, 'Parsons Henry Smith' );

DECLARE @name_to_search_for NVARCHAR(200) = N'Paul Smith Parsons';


SELECT      [per].[id]
          , [per].[name]
FROM        @persons [per]
CROSS APPLY [STRING_SPLIT]([per].[name], ' ') [perp] --Split the name column you are seaching
INNER JOIN  [STRING_SPLIT](@name_to_search_for, ' ') [srch]
    ON [srch].[value] = [perp].[value] --Split @name_to_search for and join that to the split name column
GROUP BY    [per].[id]
          , [per].[name]
HAVING      COUNT(*) >= 2; --Group and only return those with 2 or more
```

Giving you results:

```
id          name                  
----------- -----------------------
2           Paul Eric Smith     
3           Paul Parsons Cline   
6           Parsons Henry Smith
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite @TimMylott's answer as a subquery, this may be somewhat clearer.

I would imagine the performance would be the same:

```sql
SELECT      per.id
          , per.name
FROM        @persons per
WHERE
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(per.name, ' ') pSplit
    INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@name_to_search_for, ' ') sSplit
      ON sSplit.value = pSplit.value
) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim

Actually I came up with this by pure luck and some work :)

```
select id 
from #persons cross join STRING_SPLIT(@name_to_search_for, ' ')
where (DATALENGTH([name])-DATALENGTH(REPLACE([name],[value],'')))/DATALENGTH([value]) = 1
group by id
having count(value) > 1
```

Comment: Urgh that's horrible, why don't you just split the `id` also

Comment: May I ask why? Just combined some other bits, and pieced it together. And it works:)

Comment: Because it's very non-obvious code, it also only works if the split off name appears exactly once (although that you could change by doing `>= 1`). And why `DATALENGTH` and not `LEN`?

Comment: I see that, its a bit special i will give you. Was just happy and surprised that it worked. 